# Prove that the intersection of all the sets is nonempty.

Tags: combinatorics

> Given $2^{n-1}$ subsets of a set with $n$ elements with the property that any three have nonempty intersection, prove that the intersection of all the sets is nonempty.

I find this question a bit odd since why couldn't they have said we just have $2^{n-1}$ sets with this property? Also by all sets does it just mean sets in the $2^{n-1}$ subsets? I would say let each of the subsets be $A_i$. Then $A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k = A_m$ for some $i,j,k,m$ in $1 \leq i,j,k,m \leq 2^{n-1}$. Then $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_n = (A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)\cap(A_4 \cap A_5 \cap A_6) \cap \cdots \cap (A_{2^{n-1}-2} \cap A_{2^{n-1}-1} \cap A_{2^{n-1}})$. How do I show this is nonempty (given that I am interpreting the question correctly)?

Comment: I think by "all sets," it means "all sets in the set of the $2^{n-1}$ subsets".

Comment: It doesn’t say *all sets*: it says *all the sets*, where the article *the* indicates that it refers to the $2^{n-1}$ subsets.

Comment: How do I show that the set is nonempty?

Comment: You cannot assume that  $A_i\cap A_j \cap A_k=A_m$. You can only say that $A_i\cap A_j \cap A_k \ne \phi$.

Comment: @user254665 I wasn't assuming that.

Comment: You can however derive it from the second sentence of Brian Scott's answer,  so it is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SKETCH: Let $\mathscr{A}$ be the family of subsets of $S$, a set with $n$ elements. $S$ has $2^n$ subsets, so $\mathscr{A}$ contains exactly half of them. If $A\in\mathscr{A}$, then clearly $S\setminus A\notin\mathscr{A}$ (why?), so $\mathscr{A}$ contains exactly one of $A$ and $S\setminus A$ for each $A\subseteq S$.

Suppose that there is no $s\in S$ such that $\{s\}\in\mathscr{A}$, so that $S\setminus\{s\}\in\mathscr{A}$ for each $s\in S$.

- Show that if $F\subseteq S$, and $|F|\le 3$, then $S\setminus F\in\mathscr{A}$, and therefore $F\notin\mathscr{A}$. Thus, $\mathscr{A}$ contains no subset of $S$ of cardinality $3$ or less.
- Repeat the idea to show that $\mathscr{A}$ contains no subset of $S$ of cardinality $9$ or less. Then show by induction that $\mathscr{A}$ is empty.

This is impossible, so we conclude that $\{s\}\in\mathscr{A}$ for some $s\in S$.

- Suppose that $A\subseteq B\subseteq S$, and $A\in\mathscr{A}$; show that $B\in\mathscr{A}$.
- Conclude that $\mathscr{A}=\{A\subseteq S:s\in A\}$, and $\bigcap\mathscr{A}=\{s\}\ne\varnothing$.

As an aside, the argument shows that $\mathscr{A}$ is a fixed (or principal) [ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) on $S$.

Comment: Was my claim that $A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k = A_m$ for some $i,j,k,m$ in $1 \leq i,j,k,m \leq 2^{n-1}$ correct?

Comment: @user19405892: It turns out to be true, but it isn’t an obvious consequence of the hypotheses. At the moment I see no way to prove it other than to prove the final result in my answer.

Comment: Also isn't it obvious that if $A \in \mathscr{A}$ then $S \setminus A \not \in \mathscr{A}$ since $S$ contains elements not in $\mathscr{A}$ and as a result $S \setminus A \not \in \mathscr{A}$?

Comment: @user19405892: (You can get the set difference symbol with `\setminus`.) The statement that $S$ contains elements not in $\mathscr{A}$ doesn’t make sense: elements of $\mathscr{A}$ are *subsets* of $S$, not elements.

Comment: So then if $A$ is some set of subsets of $S$, how can we exclude some subsets of $S$ from $S$?

Comment: @user19405892: I’m afraid that I don’t understand what you’re trying to ask with that last comment. Have you tried filling in the details in the argument that I sketched in my answer?

Comment: What I mean is that if $\mathscr{A}$ is the family of subsets of $S$ with $2^{n-1}$ elements and $A$ is an element of $\mathscr{A}$ (which also means it is a set of subsets of $S$), then what does $S \setminus A$ even mean? $S$ is a set of elements while $A$ is a set of sets of elements of $S$.

Comment: @user19405892: I think that you’ve misunderstood the definition of $\mathscr{A}$. It’s not the set of $A\subseteq S$ such that $|A|=2^{n-1}$; it’s a collection of $2^{n-1}$ different subsets of $S$. Each $A\in\mathscr{A}$ is a subset of $S$.

Comment: For a physical example, say I have $S = \{1,2,3\}$. Then we could have $\mathscr{A} = \{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\},\{3\}\}$. Now say $A = \{2,3\}$ Do you see how now it doesn't make sense to say $S \setminus A$? How do we exclude $\{2,3\}$ from $S = \{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: @user19405892: Actually, you could not have that particular collection of sets as $\mathscr{A}$, since the intersection of the first three is empty. However, it makes perfectly good sense to talk about $S\setminus A$: $\{1,2,3\}\setminus\{2,3\}=\{1\}$.

Comment: I am not getting how "If $A\in\mathscr{A}$, then clearly $S\setminus A\notin\mathscr{A}$ (why?), so $\mathscr{A}$ contains exactly one of $A$ and $S\setminus A$ for each $A\subseteq S$."

Comment: @user19405892: Any two elements of $\mathscr{A}$ have non-empty intersection, but $A\cap(S\setminus A)=\varnothing$.

Comment: Don't you mean any three elements? Oh I see that implies any two.

Comment: How does If $A\in\mathscr{A}$, then clearly $S\setminus A\notin\mathscr{A}$ (why?)," imply that  "$\mathscr{A}$ contains exactly one of $A$ and $S\setminus A$ for each $A\subseteq S$."?

Comment: @user19405892: By itself it doesn’t. However, we also know that $\mathscr{A}$ contains half of all the subsets of $S$, and that additional fact is enough to give the stated conclusion. There are $2^{n-1}$ pairs of complementary subsets; $\mathscr{A}$ cannot contain both members of any pair, so it must contain exactly one from each pair.

Comment: Why did you say "so" then in your answer if it doesn't follow?

Comment: @user19405892: Because it *does* follow from what I had said up to that point. That includes the previous sentence.

Answer (score 9):

Let $X$ be a set with $n$ elements and $\mathcal{S}$ be a set of $2^{n-1}$ subsets of $X$ such that for any $A,B,C \in \mathcal{S}$ we have $A \cap B \cap C \neq \emptyset$.

So $\mathcal{S}$ contains half of the subsets of $X$ and if $A \subseteq X$ then $\mathcal{S}$ cannot contain both $A$ and $X \setminus A$, so exactly one of $A$ and $X \setminus A$ is in $\mathcal{S}$.

If $A,B \in \mathcal{S}$ then $A \cap B \in \mathcal{S}$, since otherwise $X \setminus (A \cap B) \in \mathcal{S}$ and $A \cap B \cap (X \setminus (A \cap B)) = \emptyset$.

Since $\mathcal{S}$ is finite, it follows that $\bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{S}}A \in \mathcal{S}$. Clearly $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{S}$.

Comment: +1 (at first glance, anyway).  First $S$ in the last paragraph has not been mathcal'd, by the way.

Comment: @ZoeH How come $S$ can't contain neither $A$ nor $X \setminus A$?

Comment: @user19405892 There are $2^{n-1}$ pairs of complementary subsets of $X$, and $\mathcal{S}$ contains at most one from each pair. Since $\mathcal{S}$ contains $2^{n-1}$ subsets of $X$, it must contain exactly one from each pair.

Comment: @ZoeH Can you elaborate why "If $A,B \in \mathcal{S}$ then $A \cap B \in \mathcal{S}$, since otherwise $X \setminus (A \cap B) \in \mathcal{S}$ and $A \cap B \cap (X \setminus (A \cap B)) = \emptyset$." Why is it true that if $A \cap B \not \in S$, then $X \setminus (A \cap B) \in S$?

Comment: @user19405892 $A \cap B$ is a subset of $X$ so either $A \cap B \in \mathcal{S}$ or $X \setminus (A \cap B) \in \mathcal{S}$ for the same reasons as in my last comment.