# Given $2^{n-1}$ subsets of a set with $n$ elements with the property that any three have nonempty intersection, prove that ....

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math, extremal-combinatorics

> Given a family of $2^{n-1}$ subsets of a set $S=\{1,2,3,...,n-1,n\}$ with the property that any three have nonempty intersection. Prove that the intersection of all the sets in this family is nonempty.

I'm interested if the finishing of the solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998945/set-of-sets-such-that-any-three-of-them-has-nonempty-intersection-show-all-of-t/2998994#comment8891325_2998994) can be done like this:

As there was constructed $W$ is $n-1$ dimensional set in
$\mathbb{F}_2^n$. Thus we have $W^{\bot}\oplus W =\mathbb{F}_2^n$
and $\dim W^{\bot} =1$, so $W^{\bot} = \{0,v\}$ for some vector
$v\ne 0$. We can assume WLOG $$v =
(\underbrace{1,1,1,...,1}_k,0,0,...,0)$$ Now each vector can be uniquely expressed with $v$ and some $w\in W$, in particulary we have
$$e_1=(1,0,0,...0) =av+w$$ for some $w\in W$ and $a \in
\mathbb{F}_2$. So if $a=0$ then $e_1\in W$ so $0=v\cdot e_1 =1$
which is impossible. Thus $a=1$ then $e_1-v \in W$ so $0=v\cdot
(e_1-v) =1-k$ which means $k$ is odd.

So each vector not in $W$ is generated with odd number of vectors
in $\{e_1,e_2,...e_k\}$ and an arbitrary number of vectors in
$\{e_{k+1},e_{k+2},...e_n\}$ where $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$ represents the standard basis of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.

Since the number of vectors not in $W$ is $2^{k-1} \cdot 2^{n-k} =
2^{n-1}$, we see if $k\geq 3$ then we have in $e_1$ and $e_2$ in
$W^C$ so sets $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are in $\mathcal{F}$ which is
impossible. So $k=1$ and all sets in $\mathcal{F}$ have $1$ in
common.

---

Non linear algebra solution: [Prove that the intersection of all the sets is nonempty.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636708/prove-that-the-intersection-of-all-the-sets-is-nonempty?rq=1)

Comment: Given any set $S$ with exactly $n$ elements and any $s \in S$, there are exactly $2^{n-1}$ subsets $T \subseteq S$ for which $s \in T$, and of course, the intersection of all of them is $\{s\}$.

Comment: @Aqua what do you think of G Trang’s comment? Is the assumption of your question regarding nonempty 3 way intersections necessary?

Comment: This is somehow converse of his claim, which holds. @kodlu

Comment: This is fine. A slight simplification is to 1) Show that $ 1 = v \cdot v = k$ so $k$ is odd and 2) Deal with $ k \geq 3$ as above. $\quad$ Note, to me, you're not doing anything substantially different from Bato's solution. In his, he argues that A) $ k \leq 2$ (in the same ways as your 2) and C) $ k \neq 2$ (which you eliminate via $k$ is odd).

Comment: A somewhat tangential question: what's the natural geometric interpretation of this question if we think of the points as vertices on an n-hypercube?

Answer (score 1):

The first step $W^{\perp}\oplus W =\mathbb F_2^n$ is already problematic. For example, take $n=2$, and $W = \{(0,0), (1,1)\}$ and the "inner product" given by $\langle (a_1,a_2), (b_1, b_2) \rangle = a_1a_2 + b_1b_2$, then $W^{\perp} = W$, so $W+W^{\perp}=W$ which is not even a direct sum.

In general, we should not expect a non-degenerate bilinear form over $F^n$ behaves like an inner product over $\mathbb R$. Even over $\mathbb R$, only those that satisfy the positivity condition serve as inner product, but positivity cannot be defined over arbitrary fields.

In this particular case, we know that $W$ is essentially all vectors whose $i$-th component is $0$, so $W^{\perp} = e_i$, and $W\oplus W^{\perp}=\mathbb F_2^n$ holds, but this is unclear before we know the conclusion of the problem.

Comment: And you don't see how to fix this? In particual, do you think linked solution is also wrong?

Comment: Not obvious to me. But the linked solution is correct. There it only uses that a $n-1$ dimensional subspace must be the kernel of a linear functional, and any linear functional is of the form $x\rightarrow \langle x,y\rangle$ for some fixed $y$. Essentially, $W^{\perp}$ should live in the dual space, while $W$ is not, so they cannot be directly compared. The "inner product" provides an isomorphism between $\mathbb F_2^n$ and its dual, but still conceptually they are quite different, and that's why the decomposition fails.