# Pairwise intersecting sets have nonempty intersection

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, problem-solving

*Definition:* Call a set of sets $\mathcal S$ **cooperative** when for every $\mathcal S'\subseteq\mathcal S$,

- *if* every two elements in $\mathcal S'$ have nonempty intersection (so $\forall X,Y\in\mathcal S'. X\cap Y\neq\varnothing$)
- *then* $\mathcal S'$ has nonempty intersection (so $\bigcap \mathcal S'=\varnothing$).

Intuitively, think of $\mathcal S$ as a set of agents (so an agent is an element $X\in\mathcal S$), and imagine that a set of agents can *cooperate* precisely when its intersection is nonempty.  Then $\mathcal S$ is cooperative when a group of agents $\mathcal S'\subseteq \mathcal S$ can cooperate, if and only if its members can cooperate pairwise.

Note that is not required here that $\bigcap\mathcal S\neq\varnothing$, since it need not be the case that every two elements in $\mathcal S$ has nonempty intersection.

*Examples:*

1. $\mathcal S=\bigl\{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\}\bigr\}$ is trivially cooperative, because no distinct elements intersect.
2. $\mathcal S=\bigl\{\{0\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\}\bigr\}$ is trivially cooperative, because $\bigcap\mathcal S=\{0\}$.
3. $\mathcal S=\bigl\{\{0\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{4\}\bigr\}$ is cooperative (even though $\bigcap\mathcal S=\varnothing$).
4. $\mathcal S=\bigl\{ \{0,1\}, \{1,2\}, \{2,0\} \}$ is not cooperative, because if we take $\mathcal S'=\mathcal S$ then every pair of elements in $\mathcal S'$ intersects, but $\bigcap\mathcal S'=\varnothing$.

Has a theory of cooperative sets been explored, and if so where?

Thank you.

(This question is not identical to, but seems related to, [Prove that the intersection of all the sets is nonempty.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636708/prove-that-the-intersection-of-all-the-sets-is-nonempty) )

Comment: The definition seems a bit odd.  First of all, in your second condition, I expect you meant to write $ \bigcap \,S'\neq \emptyset$, right?  Secondly, if $S$ is such that no two distinct elements in it intersect, then the conditions are vacuously satisfied.  Is that what you intended?  In any case, I have not seen a definition like this before.  Seems like something Economists might look at.

Comment: @lulu Your second remark was already addressed in the fourth-last paragraph of the post.

Comment: @legionwhale  I don't see how.  I am remarking that the definition vacuously implies that if, in $S$, $S_1\neq S_2\implies S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$,  then $S$ is "cooperative."  That strikes me as odd, but of course there's nothing contradictory about it.  If the OP is ok with that consequence of the definition, so be it.

Comment: @lulu But isn't the fourth-last paragraph by the OP acknowledging that may be a consequence, and thereby implying they are OK with it? There's no error in what you said, so my reply was not important, but I just thought I'd point this out.

Comment: @legionwhale Thanks for your comments.  I added examples which I hope address your points.

Comment: This is a really interesting concept. Can you provide some background as to how you came up with this?

Comment: This is reminiscent of the result that if sub-trees $(T_n)$ of a tree $T$ intersect pairwise, then $\bigcap T_n \neq \varnothing$. I think the converse is also true, where I take the converse to be "Let $G$ be a connected graph such that whenever a family of connected sub-graphs intersect pairwise, the intersection over all of them is non-empty. Then, $G$ is a tree." Thus, a graph-theoretic rephrasing may be fruitful. But considering your post history, I expect you had already thought of this.